# How can I use angular directives as custom markup for angular-ui-select2 results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ui-select2

I'm using [angular-ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) to generate a select box.

By default, results displayed in select2 lists simply display a piece of text, but select2 [provides a configuration option](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation), `formatResult` from which one can return custom markup.

I'd like to use another directive I've written as part of the result markup.

[This plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yMzxRaykL9XXqVH3iR0E?p=preview) demonstrates a minimal use case. How can I get the `projectLikesCount` directive to be compiled and displayed properly within the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the exact same but couldn't find a solution. It seems that the population of the results by `formatResult` is not in the angular lifecycle, therefore whatever markup returned by the function is displayed *as is* i.e., no directives will be "translated" into behaviour.

An example of this is that if you add the following markup:

```
<div ng-show='isNewElement'>Add new</div>
```

it will be rendered every time with no regard to the `isNewElement` value.

Considering the time this question has been unanswered I guess that it's either really easy or really complicated to achieve the desired behaviour. I'll post if I find a somewhat useful solution.